# Error: there are no arguments to 'static_assert' that depend on a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

When compiling this code, I get an error:

```
#include <cstdio>

template<size_t Index, typename T, size_t Length>
T& get(T (&arr)[Length]) {
    static_assert(Index < Length, "Index out of bounds");
    return arr[Index];
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int value = get<5>(arr);
    printf("value = %d\n", value);
}
```

Error message:

```
In function 'T& get(T (&)[Length])':
Line 5: error: there are no arguments to 'static_assert' that depend on a template parameter, so
a declaration of 'static_assert' must be available
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Can someone explain how to fix this please?

Running with gcc 4.1.2
flags:
`-O -std=c++98 -pedantic-errors -Wfatal-errors -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wwrite-strings -Wno-deprecated -Wno-unused -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-variadic-macros -fmessage-length=0 -ftemplate-depth-128 -fno-merge-constants -fno-nonansi-builtins -fno-gnu-keywords -fno-elide-constructors -fstrict-aliasing -fstack-protector-all -Winvalid-pch`

Comment: How are you compiling the code?

Comment: Tell your compiler to use c++11

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/zfbEv7v1v).  Please post your compiler, version and settings.

Comment: `static_assert` is a C++11 thing.  Do you have to use gcc 4.1.2 and c++98?

Comment: No I don't ok I'll change that, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This language feature became available in C++ only with C++11, see:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert